# Запуск системы в LXC с ядром новее чем у хостовой машаны

Tags: linux, lxc

Почему нельзя запустить в lxc систему с ядром новее чем у хостовой машины.
Пробовал  на хосте с Debian Jessie и ядом 3.16 установить Kali rolling с ядром 4.3, никак не хочет стартовать.

Answer (score 3):

LXC - это система контейнеров, а не виртуализации. Соответственно, ядро гостевой системы она загружать и использовать не умеет - все процессы используют ядро системы хоста.